# Epicor10 how to use and set a value in dataset ARInvSelDataSet

Tags: c#, epicorerp

I am currently building an e-commerce application and it will be integrated with Epicor10. I am using C# to integrate e-commerce and Epicor; So now I'm having trouble using a library class from Epicor10 to use `ARInvSelDataSet` and set a value object `ARInvSel`

Following is my code:

```
ARInvSelDataSet ArDataSet = new ARInvSelDataSet();
ArDataSet.ARInvSel[0].InvoiceNum = Invoice.InvoiceNum;
```

Comment: "... I'm having trouble ..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must either add a using directive to the top of your code:

```
using Erp.Tablesets;
```

...or fully qualify `ARInvSelDataSet` as `Erp.Tablesets.ARInvSelDataSet`

Second, you must add a reference to the contract you are using that contains the definition for the custom dataset type. I couldn't find the particular contract that holds this, but I'm assuming if you know that this specific type exists, you must have seen it within the context of the contract.